# How to generate a component in Nativescript 8 and angular

Tags: node.js, angular, nativescript

I just install all the requirements and setup my new Mac with Apple Silicon M1 Chip for Nativescript 8 development following their guide on https://nativescript.org. Now I created a new project running the command:

```
ns create
```

This asks for a name and what flavor you want, I choose Angular. Now I want to start creating new components but when trying to run the following command:

```
ng g c my-component
```

I get the following error:
**The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.**

I already have the angular cli installed (version 12 latest) globally. What command should I run to create components or other stuff like services or modules; or do I need another package to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `angular.json` in your project. And did you already install NativeScript Schematics? (`npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics`)

The file should have the following content:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "cli": {
        "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
    },
    "projects": {
        "my-project-name": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "ns"
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "my-project-name"
}
```

Replace `my-project-name` with the name of your project and run the generate command again.

[NativeScript Documentation](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/angular-cli#extending-existing-nativescript-projects-with-the-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

I use Add Angular Native Files with Visual Studio code. Pretty much works like ng g c componentName. You will just need to add the component to app.module.ts

More info here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joshdsommer.vscode-add-angular-native-files